# change colour from mailbox in Mac Mail

Tags: mail.app, color

Is it possible to change the color of the mailboxes in Mac Mail?

Here an example

[image]

Sometimes I manage to create Silver colored mailboxes by accident so I am wondering if it is possible to label them with other colors than silver and blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  A silver coloured mailbox indicates that you deleted a subfolder within that mailbox.  You need to remove the parent after removing all of the subfolders.  Then the parent will disappear as expected.

Comment: Sure. But isn't there a other way to tag the mailboxes in other colors?

Comment: @elhombre No.  Not that I know of.  If you find a solution please let us know, because I'm sure tonnes of people around here would love that, myself included.

Comment: Wondering, are there other people who want such a feature?

Comment: @elhombre - Yes.  And I have been asked by clients with Macs if such a feature does exist.

Comment: Sad that there isn't a genius out there which can make an add-on which makes this configurations possible. I will mark your response for now as an answer.